# Multinomial sample generation in python

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am able to generate binomial samples from an array of probabilities in a desired size(output should be the same size of input probabilities array shape) using the following lines of code

```
prob_list = [[0.3,0.3,0.4],[0.4,0.3,0.3]]
prob_array = np.asarray(prob_list)
y_sample = np.random.binomial(size=prob_array.shape, n=1, p=prob_array)
print(y_sample)
```

The output is

```
[[0 0 0]
[1 1 1]]
```

The shape of input probabilities(2*3) and the output samples(2*3) are same.

Is it possible to do the same with multinomial? It is possible to generate multinomial samples for a single row.

```
y_sample = np.random.multinomial(size=1, n=1, pvals=prob_array[0])
print(y_sample)
[[1 0 0]]
```

How could one generalize this to get output same as binomial(output sample shape = input probabilities shape?

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that you will have to manually loop over `prob_array`. `pvals` is currently limited to being a single 1D array of probabilities.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It would be nice if we have generalized version of multinomial. I will open a ticket regarding this issue.